# How to prevent navigating back on button click in React native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to achieve the following things.

1. Enter username and password and log in on button click.
2. Validate the above things.
3. Navigate to a new screen and print the input values username and password in new screen.
4. A logout button and on click navigate back to the login page.
5. Prevent login again just by clicking the button in the login page without inputting username and password.

   I have completed the first 4 things but I don't know how to implement the last functionality in React native.

Comment: Why you should want to login in the login page without insert the credentials? it wouldn't be a good practice. Any way, you could save those credentials in the AsyncStorage and get it when you would need them. Anyhow, there is not a really secure way to put your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly the question and honestly I'm really not certain, then resetting the navigation stack after logging out is the solution you are looking for, you can find it here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#reset